# Is there a function, preferably in Oracle, where we can select rows if any 3 conditions out of 5 are met?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to join two tables and select rows if any 3 out of 5 conditions are met. I can of course make combinations of AND's and OR's in the `where` clause but it sounds quite inefficient. Is there is a function that can do this ? The pseudo code is as below.

```
select * from tableA a,tableB b 
where a.id=b.id 
and /* if any 3 out of these 5 conditions are met: a.num = b.num, a.cat=b.cat, 
a.sun=b.sun, a.mon=b.mon, a.jan=b.jan */
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no specific function for this is a possibility:

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
  FROM tablea a
       JOIN tableb b ON a.id=b.id 
 WHERE
       (CASE WHEN a.num = b.num THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN a.cat=b.cat THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN a.sun=b.sun THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN a.mon=b.mon THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN a.jan=b.jan THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 2
```

This will give you any rows for which more than 2 conditions are met.

Note: use ANSI-style joins, it makes your query a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any built-in function that does that.

Would something like this help? Create your own function (`f_equal` in my example; simplified as much as possible) that returns `1` if values passed to it are equal or `0` if they are different. Then use it in a query along with all conditions you have, plus yet another condition: sum of values returned by the function must be `>= 3`.

Dummy example, but - I don't have anything smarter.

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_equal (par_a in varchar2, par_b in varchar2)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    return case when par_a = par_b then 1
  6                else 0
  7           end;
  8  end;
  9  /

Function created.
```

Query: lines #4 - 9 represent your current conditions, while lines #10 - 15 calculate number of *equalities*.

```
SQL> select a.deptno, a.ename, b.job
  2  from emp a cross join emp b
  3  where 1 = 1
  4    and (a.ename  = b.ename  or
  5         a.job    = b.job    or
  6         a.deptno = b.deptno or
  7         a.sal    = b.sal    or
  8         a.mgr    = b.mgr
  9        )
 10    and (f_equal(a.ename , b.ename)  +
 11         f_equal(a.job   , b.job)    +
 12         f_equal(a.deptno, b.deptno) +
 13         f_equal(a.sal   , b.sal)    +
 14         f_equal(a.mgr   , b.mgr)
 15        ) >= 3;

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
        20 SMITH      CLERK
        30 ALLEN      SALESMAN
        30 ALLEN      SALESMAN
        30 ALLEN      SALESMAN
        <snip>
```